# Swift protocol: как работать с optional var?

Tags: xcode, swift

Объявление протокола:

```
@objc protocol LeftSideMenuViewControllerProtocol {
    var containerShouldPerformContentSegueWithIdentifier:((segueIdentifier: String, object: AnyObject!) -> Void)! {set get}
    optional var containerShouldResizeLeftMenuToValue:((CGFloat) -> Void)! {set get}
}
```

Использование:

```
override var leftEmbedNavigation: CommonNavigationController? {
        willSet{
            if let nav = newValue {
                if let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as? LeftSideMenuViewControllerProtocol {
// non optional var - все работает как и ожидается
                    vc.containerShouldPerformContentSegueWithIdentifier = {
                        [weak self] (segueIdentifier: String, object: AnyObject!) in

                    }
// optional, получаю cannot assign, к тому же не знаю, поддерживает ли класс проперти
                    vc.containerShouldResizeLeftMenuToValue = { [weak self] (newConstraintValue) in

                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Собственно, вопрос: **как проверить и использовать var, помеченный в протоколе как optional?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После продолжительного ресерча могу сказать, что optional в Swift протоколах пока не особо работает, даже optional func так и не была вызвана по совершенно непонятной мне причине. Optional var будут работать, только если они readonly, то есть

```
optional var someProperty: AnyObject! { get }
```

из нее можно прочитать значение предохраняясь все тем же "?"

В моей ситуации нужно было добавить в существующий протокол новую проперти, этот протокол поддерживается очень многими классами, поэтому я решил добавить необязательную var, но Swift Beta 6 не позволил этого сделать. В итоге проблема была решена без поиска всех поддерживающих протокол классов в проекте и добавления в них обязательной, но им не нужной проперти, а с помощью нового протокола, наследника существующего:

```
@objc protocol LeftSideMenuViewControllerProtocol {
    var containerShouldPerformContentSegueWithIdentifier:((segueIdentifier: String, object: AnyObject!) -> Void)! {set get}
}

@objc protocol LeftSideMenuResizableViewController : LeftSideMenuViewControllerProtocol {
    var containerShouldResizeLeftMenuToValueHandler:((CGFloat, Bool) -> Void)! {set get}
}
```

Возможно, кому-то это окажется полезным.